# Does Mortal Remains need it's own tag? more nWoD GMC

Tags: discussion

Hunter: The Vigil currently has no announced 2nd Edition, this is likely because it's farther out than 2 years (Per Onyx Path they are not wanting to discuss anything that far out). However, they did release [Mortal Remains](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/129193/Hunter-Mortal-Remains?term=Mortal+Remains) which includes a 2nd Edition Rules update in the back of the book. This update is like The God Machine update, in that it simply provides updates to things that have changed in lieu of the God Machine Rules (such as Practical experience, Profession, etc). There is no guarantee a Hunter 2nd edition wouldn't update this further. The front of the book would apply to Hunter the Vigil 1.0 as well (It's just more Hunt supernaturals of type... info)

In order to correctly play Hunter the Vigil using World of Darkness 2.0 rules, you currently need the following books: World of Darkness 1, the God Machine Update, Hunter: the Vigil, Hunter: Mortal Remains (contains Hunter Update). These are the books on my table currently.

My question is two fold, Should we create a [hunter-mortal-remains](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hunter-mortal-remains) tag?

If we do, or do not, should questions tagged appropriate be considered to include books that weren't explicitly updated (Any of the [hunter-vigil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hunter-vigil) addons) or do I need to include [new-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness) to say that it's ok to supply answers with those questions.

The reason I'm asking this, is that [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48302/1015) ( that I deleted because I believe I asked the wrong question) was briefly retagged with [new-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness)  by accident, I presumed that tagging with [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine) and [hunter-vigil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hunter-vigil) would be enough, but I'm concerned that it may not be 100% clear with those tags that I'm not using 1.0 rules. So how should this question be tagged currently?

Comment: based on the book title, the tag should be [hunter-mortal-remains] if we create it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Bah.  Tags aren't the end all be all of describing your game's rules.  If you're playing 2e with Skills & Powers, or Pathfinder but without Ultimate Combat, we don't need tags for that, we need the question asker to use their words.
2. The emergent tagging of the site will automatically delete any tag that's not on at least 2 questions. So proactive tag creation is not desirable by design. If it needs to happen, it'll happen. Looks like there's not enough volume of this edge case to let it happen yet.